# Compatibility serenity-jira-plugin with Jira

Tags: jira, serenity-bdd

We are testing Serenity-Jira-Plugin 4.0.33 with Jira 8.13.2, but it doesn't seem to be aligning with the returned JSON schema from the Jira API. Does anyone know about any compatibility matrix for Jira? Thanks in advance!